# Spring Boot now displaying the index.jsp page

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am a newbie with Spring boot.
I am trying to return my index page in the controller but I am not able to. Its just returning the word index in the output. Here's my code:

**Controller class:**

```
@RestController
public class IMEIController {


@Autowired
private IValidateIMEI iValidateIMEI;

@GetMapping("/")
public String home() {
    return "index";
}
}
```

This is my structure
[image]

**Application.properties file**

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with `@RestController`. Use `@Controller` annotation instead.
`@RestController` is use to create RESTful web services.

Here some articles if you need to know more.

1. [The Spring @Controller and @RestController Annotations](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-controller-vs-restcontroller)

Comment: Now its sending an error 

Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun Oct 10 14:42:53 IST 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).




Also I need to create a rest API with spring boot

Comment: What is the URL you calling?

Comment: its localhost:8080/

Comment: Update `public String home()` method to `public String home(Model model)`

Comment: No change sadly

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot does not work directly with JSPs. You will have to add tomcat Jasper embedded dependency to get it working.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-jsp

Also change @RestController to @controller.

And if you want to develop Rest + JSP in the same controller then use @Controller on class level and add @ResponseBody for the rest API methods which will return response in the body instead of  returning a JSP page.

Answer (score 0):

Just add your jsp folder in build path of the project:-

Right click on the project > Build Path > Configure Build path > Deployment Assembly > Add(right hand side) > Folder > Add your views folder > Apply and Close

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).